# Get all webcams using wia

Tags: c#, wia

I want to take photos from webcam using C# application. First of all I'm going to get list of all webcams on PC. I find this example:

```
        System.Collections.Generic.List<DeviceInfoClass> devs =
                                      new List<DeviceInfoClass>();

        WIA.Collection devsCol =
                        this.WiaObj.Devices as WIALib.CollectionClass;
        foreach (object obj in devsCol)
        {
            WIA.DeviceInfoClass dev = (WIA.DeviceInfoClass)
              System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(
              obj, typeof(WIA.DeviceInfoClass));
            if (dev.Type.Contains("Video") == true)
            {
                devs.Add(dev);
            }
            else
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(dev);
            }
        }
        Devices = devs.ToArray();
        if (Devices.Length > 0)
        {
            DefaultDevice = Devices[0];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No Cameras Detected");
        }

        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(devsCol);
        GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(devs);
```

But the problem is that I have Win 7 and using Wia 2.0(wiaut.dll) and there is no CollectionClass.
So, how can I get list of all webcams using WiA 2.0(wiaut.dll)?

Comment: All 3 lines of code are seemingly unrelated...

Comment: @leppie Oh, actually that's my fault. But problem is the same.